# Всплывающий блок

Tags: javascript, jquery

На странице есть кнопка, как сделать так, чтобы при клике на кнопку, всплывал блок div? Спасибо

Comment: https://for-net.ru/view_post.php?id=99

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function()
{

    $('.btn-alert').on('click', function(event) 
 { 
        $(".alert-message").append('<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade in"><a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a><h3>success alert</h3><BR><p> action was a success</p></div>');
 });

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<section class="container">
<div class="row">  
<div class="col-md-12"> 


<h3>Bootstrap Alert Message</h3>

<button id="alert1" class="btn btn-alert btn-success" type="button">Success</button>
<div class="alert-message"> </div>
</div>
</div>
</section>
```